# Скрипт при подключении к openvpn

Tags: база-данных, bash, openvpn

На сервере поднята база данных и openvpn. Подскажите можно ли как-то создать скрипт приветствия для клиентов openvpn?
Т.е. при подключении клиента к vpn, выводилось всплывающее окно с именем клиента и его время до следующей оплаты. Окно должно отображаться на любых устройствах, андроид, виндовс, ios.

Comment: И при чем здесь PHP?

Comment: на нем предпочтительно написать скрипт, либо на bash

Comment: понятно, что делать это должен openvpn-клиент. вот с конкретными реализациями клиентов, которыми пользуются ваши пользователи, и надо разбираться. // я лично не встречал умеющей такое реализации, но реализаций клиентов — вагон и маленькая тележка. вполне возможно, что в какой-то из них такое имеется.